# Are there any problems using HTML5 markup on a non-HTML5 DOCTYPE?

Tags: html, doctype

If I use the transitional DOCTYPE `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`
but use HTML5 markup on my page, will I incur any deleterious side effects, other than receiving validation errors?

Comment: Note: the validation errors _do_ affect search engine results/parsing; though, in my specific case, that's not an issue I'm concerned with.

Comment: FWIW, that's not the HTML 4.01 Transitional doctype. This is: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`. The browsers' behavioural differences between that and `<!DOCTYPE html>` are small and not HTML5 specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, no. Browsers these days just check for the presence of *A* doctype, not which one. But it could be that I'm missing something - why don't you just try and see?

Comment: I have tried, and ostensibly, it seems ok, but I wanted to know if there was some gotcha that I should be aware of.